# Clear Interval does not work currently

Tags: jquery, ajax, setinterval, clearinterval

I try to display increase progress bar  in my page . I run two ajax together in the same time . I need to when ajax done , stop `setInterval` with  `clearInterval(GetProgress);` statement but does not  work.

What is problem?

```
 var RefreshCheapCharters = function (el) {
         $(el).append('<i class="fa fa-spinner Rotate360"></i>');
         $.when(RefreshProgress(3),
         $.ajax({
              url: '/CheapTravel/CheapCharters/',
              type: "POST",
              success:function (result) {
                         console.log(result);
                         $(el).find('.fa-spinner').remove();
                         clearInterval(GetProgress);
                         $('.progress-bar').css('width', 0 + '%').text('');
                     },
                 error: function (jqXhr, textStates, errorThrown) {
                     console.log(errorThrown);
                     $(el).find('.fa-spinner').remove();
                     clearInterval(GetProgress);
                     $('.progress-bar').css('width', 0 + '%').text('');
                 }
             })
           );   
        };
        var RefreshProgress = function (reserveType) {
            setInterval(function () {
                GetProgress(reserveType);
            }, 10000);

        };
        var GetProgress = function (reserveType) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/CheapTravel/RefreshProgress',
                data: { reserveType: reserveType },
                type: "POST",
                success:
                    function (result) {
                        $('.progress-bar').css('width', result + '%').text(result + '% انجام شد');
                    },
                error: function (jqXhr, textStates, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                    $('.progress-bar').css('width', 0);
                    console.log('خطای سیستمی');
                    clearInterval(GetProgress);
                }
            });
 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `clearInterval()` method clears a timer set with the `setInterval()` method.

The ID value returned by `setInterval()` is used as the parameter for the `clearInterval()` method, so you need to retrieve this ID value.

```
var myIntervalID = setInterval(function () {
    GetProgress(reserveType);
}, 10000);

clearInterval(myIntervalID);
```

You are passing a function (`GetProgress`) to `clearInterval()`, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```js
setInterval(function () {
    GetProgress(reserveType);
}, 10000);
```

Should become:

**At the top of file**

```
var myInterval;
```

**Then in the function**

```
myInterval = setInterval(GetProgress(reserveType), 10000);
```

---

When clearing the interval you are passing the called function as an argument

```
clearInterval(GetProgress);
```

**Pass the variable name instead of the called function**

```
clearInterval(myInterval);
```

What you are doing in setting the interval is you pass an anonymous function and in that function you call the function that is needed. No need to pass the anonymous function in there just pass the function that needs to be executed.